# Registering for GWT DOM Events

Tags: events, gwt

This might be a stupid question but I write a class called test lets say in GWT and I want to have it listen for DOM events. How would I do that?

I have tried implementing lets say the KeyPressHandler and then implementing the method onKeyPress() and I place an Window.alert("Event") in the body. Though nothing happens when I test it pressing any key.

I have looked into the Google documentation [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiDom.html) but I really though GWT made it very easy to get these DOM events.

**Example**

I have a player class and I want to incerment its x value when the user press the left arrow key. So I would impelment the KeyPresshanlder and the method onKeyPress(). Though this doesn't work, is there somthing more I need to do?

Comment: What type of events do you want to keep track of? Could you provide a use case/example you are trying to implement?

Comment: I have a player class and I want to incerment its x value when the user press the left arrow key. So I would impelment the KeyPresshanlder and the method onKeyPress(). Though this doesn't work, is there somthing more I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add that handler to a Widget that implements [`HasKeyPressHandlers`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/HasKeyPressHandlers.html) - a common choice is wrapping your widget/player in a [`FocusPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusPanel.html) (it implements a *lot* of handlers - key, mouse, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use GwtQuery which provides events without using widgets. It has interface similar to jQuery.